# Отрицательная числа в запросе показало 0

Tags: mysql, дата, select

Есть таблица "sale" в нем две столбца дат StartDate и FinishDate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сделал запрос чтобы получить остаток даты между двумя датами

```
select x.*, (TO_DAYS(x.MaxFinishDate)-TO_DAYS(CURDATE())) AS OstatokDate  from(
select UserID, CURDATE() AS Today, MAX(FinishDate) as MaxFinishDate
from sale 
group by UserID) as x
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В маем случае запрос показывает -25 как сделать в запросе если число отрицательное показало 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по существу вопроса `GREATEST()` выбирает максимум из двух значений.
в остальном, для разницы в датах есть `datediff`, и  `curdate` в подзапросе избыточен. что-то вроде этого:

```
SELECT UserID
     , CURDATE() AS today
     , MaxFinishDate as maxDate
     , GREATEST(0, DATEDIFF(MaxFinishDate, CURDATE())) AS days
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, MAX(FinishDate) as MaxFinishDate
    FROM sale 
    GROUP BY UserID
  ) as x
```

Comment: пищит Error Code : 1305
FUNCTION 1tv.DATE_DIFF does not exist

Comment: @ariana вы загуглить и исправить опечатку не в состоянии?

Comment: хорошо и CURDATE() AS today, пробел(запятая) тоже удалите чтобы все работало, спасибо)

Comment: запятая там а не пробел. зы: в принципе то можно и без подзапроса ведь задачу решать